# What is the best way to check file creation permissions in java

Tags: java, file, permissions, directory, file-permissions

I need to check for file creation permissions for specific directory.

I've tried:

```
try {
    AccessController.checkPermission(new FilePermission("directory_path", "write"));
    // Have permission
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    // Doesn't have permission
}
```

... but this always throws SecurityException (as far as I've understood this checks not underlying fs permissions but some JVM settings that should be configured explicitly).

Another possible way was to use something like this:

```
File f = new File("directory_path");
if(f.canWrite()) {
    // Have permission
} else {
    // Doesn't have permission
}
```

... but this returns true even if I cannot create file in specified directory (For example I cannot create file in "c:\" when I run my app under user without admin privileges, but f.canWrite() returns true).

In the end I've done hack similar to this:

```
File f = new File("directory_path");
try {
    File.createTempFile("check", null, f).delete();

    // Have permission
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Doesn't have permission
}
```

... but this may serve only as a temporary solution since I need to get such permissions for almost all folders on client's fs.

Does anybody know how to get REAL file creation permissions nicely, without causing performance issues and hacks described above?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test the availability/usability of any resource is to try to use it. In this case, `new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, name))`. It will throw an `IOException` if the directory isn't writable, or the file already exists and isn't writable, etc etc etc. The operating system already has to do all those checks when you execute that code: there is no point in trying to duplicate it all, and even if you get it 100% right, which is unlikely, you are still introducing a timing window in which the previously 'true' condition can become 'false' due to asynchronous activity. You have to catch exceptions from the file creation anyway, and write code in the catch block to handle them: why write all that twice?

Comment: What You've described is basically the same thing I do in 3rd listing. As I've said I have to collect file creation permissions for almost all fs present on PC.I will use this info for analysis and later file creation in some of these directories. This mean that I will have possibility of this "asynchronous activity" and I am ok with this. The problem is that create/remove file in every folder just to figure out is there permissions doesn't look like a good soution...